# is it possible to give gradient blur effect in Custom paint in Flutter like below picture?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, paint, flutter-custompaint

I am coding the below output and i get the design i want but not able to get the blur effect inside the canvas.
This is the output i am trying to build, 
[image: Output i want]

This is what i have tried,
[image: My Output]

Here is the Code,

```
class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {

@override



 void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint0 = Paint()
      ..color = const Color.fromARGB(128,255,255,255)
    ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
    ..strokeWidth = 2.0;

Path path0 = Path();
path0.moveTo(size.width * 0.1500300, size.height * 0.1238500);
path0.cubicTo(
    size.width * 0.0037200,
    size.height * 0.1023500,
    size.width * 0.0522600,
    size.height * 0.7552500,
    size.width * 0.1500500,
    size.height * 0.8761750);
path0.cubicTo(
    size.width * 0.2767600,
    size.height * 0.8761750,
    size.width * 0.7234100,
    size.height * 0.8735500,
    size.width * 0.8501100,
    size.height * 0.8735500);
path0.cubicTo(
    size.width * 0.9464300,
    size.height * 0.7575750,
    size.width * 0.9946900,
    size.height * 0.0944750,
    size.width * 0.8496900,
    size.height * 0.1268750);
path0.cubicTo(
    size.width * 0.7230200,
    size.height * 0.1268750,
    size.width * 0.5303400,
    size.height * 0.1263500,
    size.width * 0.1500300,
    size.height * 0.1238500);
path0.close();
canvas.drawPath(path0, paint0);


}

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try with `Colors.black12` for paint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to bother yourself with a `CustomPainter` everything can be done with a `Container` and a `BackdropFilter` widgets.

### Code sample

```dart
class BlurredBottomBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const BlurredBottomBar({
    super.key,
    required this.items,
    required this.currentIndex,
    required this.onItemTapped,
  });

  final int currentIndex;
  final void Function(int index) onItemTapped;
  final List<IconData> items;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    final bottomNavigationBarTheme = theme.bottomNavigationBarTheme;

    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.white,
          strokeAlign: BorderSide.strokeAlignOutside,
        ),
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(
          top: Radius.circular(9),
          bottom: Radius.circular(36),
        ),
      ),
      child: BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2, sigmaY: 2),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () => onItemTapped(i),
                icon: Icon(
                  items[i],
                  color: i == currentIndex
                      ? bottomNavigationBarTheme.selectedItemColor
                      : bottomNavigationBarTheme.unselectedItemColor,
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Usage

```dart
Scaffold(
  extendBody: true,
  bottomNavigationBar: BlurredBottomBar(
    currentIndex: 0,
    items: const [
      Icons.home,
      Icons.grid_view,
      Icons.notifications_outlined,
      Icons.settings_outlined,
    ],
    onItemTapped: (index) {
      // ...
    },
  ),
  body: ...,
);
```

### Screenshot

[image]

[You can try the full example on zapp.run](https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zhq6067ehq70?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart)

Comment: The bounty is for a solution only inside a custom painter. Not for any "workaround" which is depends on BackdropFilter

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to get up to the very closed result you needed. Especially the blur effect. The key elements used are [ClipRRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html), [ClipPath](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html), [BackdropFilter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BackdropFilter-class.html).
I have used other elements as well, but it's upto you. The idea is to clip the rectangle diagonally, so that one side is blurred and other side is transparent. Also clipping restricts the effect of backdrop filter's outside the rectangle, otherwise it causes blur effect on the entire screen.
If you play around a little with various color values with opacity, you can get the exact result.
You can also look for the results at this [Dartpad link](https://dartpad.dev/?id=57e385bd13062e6e437a2510194d0ff4)

`main.dart file.`

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: false,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  Widget drawRowItem(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
            border: Border.all(
                width: 2, color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 40, 40, 40))),
        height: 200,
        child: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.home_filled,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 8),
              Text(
                "Samle Item",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget drawRowItems(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 56,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 56,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 22),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          drawRowItem(context),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 16,
          ),
          drawRowItem(context)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<int> items = List.filled(40, 0);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          ListView(
            children: items.map((e) {
              return drawRowItems(context);
            }).toList(),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 18,
            left: 18,
            right: 18,
            height: 86,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                      width: 2, color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 40, 40, 40)),
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(24),
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(52),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(52)),
                 color: const Color.fromARGB(100, 40, 40, 40)
              ),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(24),
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(52),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(52)),
                child: ClipPath(
                  clipper: MyCustomClipper(),
                  child: BackdropFilter(
                    filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaY: 5, sigmaX: 5),
                    child: Container(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const Positioned(
            bottom: 18,
            left: 22,
            right: 22,
            height: 86,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.home_outlined,
                  color: Colors.amber,
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.apps,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.notifications_outlined,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.settings_outlined,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(64,size.height);
    path.lineTo(0,size.height);
    path.lineTo(0,0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The bounty is for a solution only inside a custom painter. Not for any "workaround" which is depends on BackdropFilter

Comment: @HamedHamedi, you are right. I will update the answer and get back to you. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @HamedHamedi, sorry, without backdrop filter, I am unable to produce the desired result for blur effect. Maybe someone can come up with a better solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if you have a strict requirement to use a custom paint but you can achieve that effect using the `BackdropFilter` and using an `ImageFilter.blur` as your filter value.

Comment: Yes, I have to make the same bottom navigation bar design.

Comment: You can make the same bottom navigation design using the BackgropFilter and using a row for your children.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BackdropFilter`. Demo usage:

```
            BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3.0, sigmaY: 3.0),
                child: Container(
                  width: 334.66,
                  height: 212.66,
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Demo Text',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: I tried this but i want that same shape of blur for navigationbar

Comment: So, wrap that widget with BackdropFilter

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to pass `extendBody` as `true` to the Scaffold, so that the body will extend over the bottom navigation bar, then add the bottomNavigationBar with BackDropFilter like this,

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(12.0),
            topRight: Radius.circular(12.0),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(36.0),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(36.0),
          ),
          child: BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(
              sigmaX: 2.0,
              sigmaY: 2.0,
            ),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.orange.withOpacity(0.4)),
              child: BottomNavigationBar(
                elevation: 0,
                type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                unselectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                onTap: (int index) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedIndex = index;
                  });
                },
                currentIndex: selectedIndex,
                items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Home"),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: "Profile"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Here I have tried to create the UI shared in the question, I have added 2 `BottomNavigationBarItem` inside the `BackDropFilter` in order to blur the background of the bottom navigation bar. [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=c774e5a8bc1ee482628ae5d9825ac581) is full code for reference.

Comment: The bounty is for a solution only inside a custom painter. Not for any "workaround" which is depends on BackdropFilter